# Webstorm filewatchers not working

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm writing Typescript for the client side in Webstorm. The filewatcher often does not change the underlying .js file as soon as the .ts file is modified. It often doesn't do that for hours. This makes it very hard to debug. How can I speed it up to get the .js files generated as soon as changes are saved. Here's my filewatcher configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using the `--out` parameter. Try to use AMD for quicker single file compiles (https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#amd--requirejs-support) https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#advantage-of-using-amdloader-option

Comment: Hi, Can you please answer the question on this page? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592191/trying-to-integrate-requirejs-into-a-typescript-project